# Performance Issue in INFRAGISTICS print preview rendering

Tags: datagrid, reporting, infragistics, xamdatagrid, print-preview

I am generating print preview using report class object of **Infragistics.Windows.Reporting** namespace,

but the problem is when dealing with large amount of data, application usually becomes irreponsive and gets stuck while preview generation also takes several minutes which is not desired, i am attaching my sample application here, please suggest any good workaround or solution for it

[download sample project](http://www.4shared.com/zip/mgybq0zN/DataGridPrinting.html)

Comment: SO is for specific issues you encounter.  No one is going to review your entire application.  Do some performance profiling to determine where the slowdown occurs; Red Gate provides a free trial of ANTS.

Comment: @UmairNoor I also wouldn't expect anyone to sign up for a third party service just to be able to download your sample.